# Rolling a dice and finding the probability.

Tags: probability

[image]

- A. The quantity in Column A is greater
- B. The quantity in Column B is greater
- C. The two quantities are equal
- D. The relationship cannot be determined from the information given
  Which will be the answer?

> I have calculated i this way: 
>   There are 3 sixes in the 3 dices. and the total dices are 216. So the probability is $3/216$

Comment: If $n$ is big enough, clearly quantity $A$ is bigger.  But if $n$ is just $3$, then the expected number of $6$'s is exactly $1/2$, so the probability of getting at least one $6$ is strictly less than $1/2$.  So the answer is $D$.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion it's D:

The probability of getting at least one six is the complement of getting no sixes
$$1 - {\left( {\frac{5}{6}} \right)^n}
% MathType!MTEF!2!1!+-
% feaagKart1ev2aaatCvAUfeBSjuyZL2yd9gzLbvyNv2CaerbnfgDOP
% uy49vtHrhAaeXatLxBI9gBaerbuLwBLnhiov2DGi1BTfMBaerbd9wD
% YLwzYbItLDharqqtubsr4rNCHbGeaGqiVu0Je9sqqrpepC0xbbL8F4
% rqqrFfpeea0xe9Lq-Jc9vqaqpepm0xbba9pwe9Q8fs0-yqaqpepae9
% pg0FirpepeKkFr0xfr-xfr-xb9adbaqaaeaacaGaaiaadeWaaqaada
% qbaaGcbaGaaGymaiabgkHiTmaabmaabaWaaSaaaeaacaaI1aaabaGa
% aGOnaaaaaiaawIcacaGLPaaadaahaaWcbeqaaabaaaaaaaaapeGaam
% OBaaaaaaa!40A6!
$$
A=at least one six in n throws

If n=3 then:

$$P({\rm{A) = 1 - }}{\left( {\frac{5}{6}} \right)^3} = 1 - \frac{{125}}{{216}} = \frac{{91}}{{216}} < \frac{1}{2}
% MathType!MTEF!2!1!+-
% feaagKart1ev2aaatCvAUfeBSjuyZL2yd9gzLbvyNv2CaerbnfgDOP
% uy49vtHrhAaeXatLxBI9gBaerbuLwBLnhiov2DGi1BTfMBaerbd9wD
% YLwzYbItLDharqqtubsr4rNCHbGeaGqiVu0Je9sqqrpepC0xbbL8F4
% rqqrFfpeea0xe9Lq-Jc9vqaqpepm0xbba9pwe9Q8fs0-yqaqpepae9
% pg0FirpepeKkFr0xfr-xfr-xb9adbaqaaeaacaGaaiaadeWaaqaada
% qbaaGcbaGaamiuaiaacIcacaqGHbGaaeiDaiaabccacaqGSbGaaeyz
% aiaabggacaqGZbGaaeiDaiaabccacaqGVbGaaeOBaiaabwgacaqGGa
% Gaae4CaiaabMgacaqG4bGaaeykaiaab2dacaqGXaGaaeylamaabmaa
% baWaaSaaaeaacaaI1aaabaGaaGOnaaaaaiaawIcacaGLPaaadaahaa
% WcbeqaaabaaaaaaaaapeGaaG4maaaak8aacqGH9aqpcaaIXaGaeyOe
% I0YaaSaaaeaacaaIXaGaaGOmaiaaiwdaaeaacaaIYaGaaGymaiaaiA
% daaaGaeyypa0ZaaSaaaeaacaaI5aGaaGymaaqaaiaaikdacaaIXaGa
% aGOnaaaacqGH8aapdaWcaaqaaiaaigdaaeaacaaIYaaaaaaa!5FC7!
$$
Since
$${\left( {\frac{5}{6}} \right)^n}
% MathType!MTEF!2!1!+-
% feaagKart1ev2aaatCvAUfeBSjuyZL2yd9gzLbvyNv2CaerbnfgDOP
% uy49vtHrhAaeXatLxBI9gBaerbuLwBLnhiov2DGi1BTfMBaerbd9wD
% YLwzYbItLDharqqtubsr4rNCHbGeaGqiVu0Je9sqqrpepC0xbbL8F4
% rqqrFfpeea0xe9Lq-Jc9vqaqpepm0xbba9pwe9Q8fs0-yqaqpepae9
% pg0FirpepeKkFr0xfr-xfr-xb9adbaqaaeaacaGaaiaadeWaaqaada
% qbaaGcbaGaaeylamaabmaabaWaaSaaaeaacaaI1aaabaGaaGOnaaaa
% aiaawIcacaGLPaaadaahaaWcbeqaaiaad6gaaaaaaa!3F8E!
$$
Gets smaller as n increases the probability of at least one six gets bigger and will exceed half when n  is greater than three.

Comment: Can I write in this way that probability of getting 6 is $(\frac16)^n$?